# How to add extra breakpoint in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, upgrade, bootstrap-5, breakpoints

I upgraded from Bootstrap 4 to 5 in a project. The BS4 project has an extra breakpoint. In BS5 it no longer works as expected.
What is the correct way in Bootstrap 5 to add an additional custom breakpoint?

The existing code is:
$grid breakpoints: (
xs: 0,
sm: 576px,
md: 768px,
lg: 992px,
xl: 1200px,
xxl: 1540px,
xxxl: 2160px
);

Comment: Please read and follow this - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#grid-tiers

Answer (score 3):

This Can be achieved via Sass Customization and recompile.

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
        $grid-breakpoints: (
      xs: 0,
      xsm: 362px,
      sm: 576px,
      md: 768px,
      lg: 992px,
      xl: 1200px,
      xxl: 1400px
    );
        @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
    @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
        @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

For more info:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCX3QVl_PiI